# Compile one Objective C iOS class before share code with others

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks

I have to share my source code with someone else but I don't want them to look in certain classes (or categories). Can I compile them into binary file with h file outside? Something like iOS framework that displays only header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them in a custom framework and link to your project. Look [here](http://allforiphone.sosblog.com/All-for-iPhone-b1/Custom-Framework-Update-b1-p31.htm).

Comment: Martin: Accept the answer, so Vignesh gains the reputation-points for this solution. That's the meaning of this "forum".